# Where could I see the top question-askers?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics

I have tried to find a list of the "most question posters" on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to do so.

I always wondered if I'm the one with the most questions...

Comment: You can see the top askers *per tag*, but I’m not sure if there’s a page that shows them *overall*. You can certainly obtain the stats via SEDE if you’re handy with SQL (or you can convince rene to write the code for you).

Comment: It was already done; here are the top 10 question askers: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1148320/top-askers-of-so?Num=10

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive. Think we can still get rene to do it, @Heretic?

Comment: @CodyGray Apparently :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1178211?UserId=1390192) does that for you:

It takes your userid to show where you are in the overall ranking of askers and then the top 50,000.

```sql
;with askers as
(
select 
       RANK() OVER(order by count(*) desc) [rank]
       , concat('site://users/', owneruserid, '|', displayname) [User name]
       , owneruserid
     , count(*) [Questions Asked]
from posts
inner join users on owneruserid = users.id
where posttypeid = 1 -- Q 
group by owneruserid, displayname
)

select rank, [User name], [questions asked]
from askers
where owneruserid = ##userid:int?1390192##
union all
select rank, [User name], [questions asked]
from askers
```

When run today this will be your result:

[image]

You can find the documentation for the database schema in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shout-out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) she wrote.
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).